# Allowing a regular user to listen to a port below 1024

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, privileges, authbind

I need to allow a non-root user to run a server listening on port tcp/80.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This question is open to interpretation.  I'm hoping that you mean "you have created a new system service that you (as root) would like to run in an unprivileged account for security reasons" (considered good practice) and not "I have a user that's asked if they can run their own web server on my system, how do I allow them access?" (considered rather poor practice)

Comment: @Ptolemy, the actual reason is: my machine is behind a firewall that blocks any port but the 80. I want to host a server (which doesn't drop privileges!), thus need to have it listening on port 80, but don't trust it to run as root (for obvious security reasons). I'm allowed to do this, if you care.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/program`

this will work for specific processes. But to allow a particular user to bind to ports below 1024 you will have to add him to sudoers.

Have a look at this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-1024-on-li) for more.

Answer (score 39):

*(Some of these methods have been mentioned in other answers; I'm giving several possible choices in rough order of preference.)*

You can redirect the low port to a high port and listen on the high port.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1080
```

You can start your server as root and drop privileges after it's started listening on the privileged port. Preferably, rather than coding that yourself, start your server from a wrapper that does the job for you. If your server starts one instance per connection, start it from [`inetd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd) (or a similar program such as [`xinetd`](http://www.xinetd.org/)). For `inetd`, use a line like this in `/etc/inetd.conf`:

```
http  stream  tcp  nowait  username:groupname  /path/to/server/executable  argv[0] argv[1]…
```

If your server listens in a single instance, start it from a program such as [`authbind`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind). Either create an empty file `/etc/authbind/byport/80` and make it executable to the user running the server; or create `/etc/authbind/byuid/1234`, where 1234 is the UID running the server, containing the line `0.0.0.0/0:80,80`.

If your server executable is stored on a filesystem that supports capabilities, you can give it the [`cap_net_bind_service`](http://www.lids.org/lids-howto/node46.html) [capability](http://www.friedhoff.org/posixfilecaps.html). Beware that capabilities are still relatively new and [still have a few kinks](http://www.sevagas.com/?POSIX-file-capabilities-the-dark).

```
setcap cap_net_bind_service=ep /path/to/server/executable
```

Comment: In every case I've had to deal with, the executable was a script that launched java or python.  As a guy without 10 hours to spend on the fine points, your iptables solution covers it painlessly.

Comment: For the iptables solution, I had to also add a filter rule like `-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1080 -j ACCEPT` otherwise it would not work (I also have a `-j DROP` catch-all.)  So I'm left with two listening sockets.

Answer (score 8):

If the service is run by systemd,

1. set the desired port in the service configuration
2. open the unit file (usually `/etc/systemd/system/something.service`), go to the `[Service]` section, add a new line `AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` and save the file
3. reload the file: `systemctl daemon-reload`
4. (re)start the service: `systemctl start something` or `systemctl restart something`

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux#comment66086522_21653102)

Answer (score 6):

[Authbind](http://manned.org/authbind.1), @Gilles already mentioned it, but I'd like to expand on it a bit.

It has convenient access control (details in man page): you can filter access by port, interface address, uid, ranges of address or port and combination of these.

It has very useful parameter `--depth`:

> --depth *levels*
>
> Causes  authbind  to  affect programs which are levels deep in the calling graph.
>   The default is 1.

"Levels deep" means when a script (or program), runs another script it descends a level. So if you have `--depth 5` it means on levels 1 (or is it 0?) through 5 you have permission to bind, whereas on level 6 and on, you don't. Useful when you want a script to have access, but not programs that it runs with or without your knowledge.

---

To illustrate, you could have something like this: for sake of security, you have a user `java` that is meant to only run java and you want to give him access to port 80:

```
echo > /etc/authbind/byport/80
chown root:java /etc/authbind/byport/80
chmod 710 /etc/authbind/byport/80
```

I've created the `../byport/80 file`, given it to `java` users group (each user has it's own group), and made it executable by group, which means it's executable by `java` user. If you're giving access by port, the file has to be executable by the user that should have access, so we did that.

This might be enough for the average Joe, but because you know how to use the `--depth` parameter, you run (as `java` user) `authbind --depth [depth] my_web_app's_start_script` starting at `--depth 1` and working your way up until you find the smallest depth that works and use that.

[Read the man page for details](http://manned.org/authbind.1).

Answer (score 4):

You could use [netcat or xinetd](http://heronforge.net/redhat/node11.html) or iptables port forwarding, or use apache as a front end proxy and run the process on a non-privileged port.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that this is not possible by design.

The long answer is that in the open source worlds there are lots of people playing with the design and coming up with alternate methods. In general it is widely accepted practice that this should not be possible. The fact that you are trying probably means you have another design fault in your system and should reconsider your whole system architecture in light of *nix best practices and security implications.

That said, one program for authorizing non-root access to low ports is [authbind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind). Both [selinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) and [grsecurity](http://grsecurity.net/) also provide frameworks for such fine tuned authentications.

Lastly, if you want specific users to run specific programs as root and what you really need is just to allow a user to restart apache or something like that, `sudo` is your friend!

Comment: Port "security" doesn't really give you very much in the modern world.

Comment: @pjc50: Yes it does. It's about implied trust. Low port numbers imply high trust. SSH, POP, FTP and other daemons are expected to ask for system level passwords and other credentials when their ports are opened. If users were allowed to listen on low ports on a box, they could start phony daemons on unused (or crashed) ports and harvest passwords from unsuspecting users. Those passwords could then be used on that box to compromise other accounts, including root.

Comment: That's a pretty weak form of security. If you've connected to something and not done a certificate transaction then you have no idea of who you're talking to - ie MITM attacks.

Comment: @pjc50: I'd be perfectly happy if you convinced the world that unauthenticated SMTP is a BadIdea™ along with every other protocol parading itself in the < 1024 port range with no security other than the assumption that the box is clean. Knock yourself out.

Comment: I suppose what's needed is chown for ports: then you could "chown mail port25" then (a) your mail daemon doesn't need to be started with root privs and (b) nobody else can hijack it.

Comment: That would fix one of two problems and create another. It would allow administrators to adopt even more bad practices, and anybody talking to the box from the outside would be even LESS assured that port 25 on a given box was going to be answered by an authorized/authoritative daemon. We can already run a mail daemon as a restricted user, but we have to first get it listening on the socket as root then downgrade it's permissions. This assures people that at the very least the system administrator and not some user was responsible for setting up the daemons on anything < 1024.

Comment: While this may have been true "by design" when linux was in its infancy, it makes very little sense then and now. Security is all about what a user can  and can't do. Allowing only the root user to use port 80, for example, is a huge security risk, because it means you have to give root access to people who need to use port 80 but *shouldn't* have root access. If you trust non-root user X to use port 80, you should be able to encode that trust in your OS. Luckily, like you mentioned, there are crappy work-arounds that allow this, like authbind.

Comment: @BT You're missing more than half the picture here. Allowing non-privileged users to start up daemons on standardized low-port service locations is  a much larger issue than the minor inconvenience of having to configure ways for give users the privileges they need. Contrary to your comment, you do _NOT_ need to (and should not) give root access to users just because they need to start a service on port 80. And any system that doesn't require admin rights to start services on port 80 shouldn't be forward-facing anyway—that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: "Allowing non-privileged users to start up daemons on standardized low-port service locations is a much larger issue" - how so? There is no reason that a "standard port" necessarily has anything to do with security.

Comment: In 2019 (and equally four years ago), I would say it would be wrong to trust a service just because its port number is low. Therefore there is no good reason to restrict non-root users from binding to one.

Comment: First. It is from Unix time, not from Linux.
Second.  There are real reasons not to allow any user to run on low numbered ports.  Because if anyone can run them, any one can start a web browser or mail without the system administrator knowing.  No, it is not an all security solution, but it is one of many steps.
And no, you shouldn't still run webservers as root, you should drop priv after get acces to the port.  The root privs only needed when starting.
Yes, MS, I look at you.  Thanks for all hacking done from you.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the iptables PREROUTING REDIRECT method, but found that it also affects forwarded packets. That is, if the machine is also forwarding packets between interfaces (e.g. if it's acting as a Wi-Fi access point connected to an Ethernet network), then the iptables rule will also catch connected clients' connections to Internet destinations, and redirect them to the machine. That's not what I wanted—I only wanted to redirect connections that were directed to the machine itself.

One possibility is to use TCP port forwarding. E.g. using `socat`:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:www,reuseaddr,fork TCP4:localhost:8080
```

However one disadvantage with that method is, the application that is listening on port 8080 then doesn't know the source address of incoming connections (e.g. for logging or other identification purposes).