# Unset `setcap` additional capabilities on executable

Tags: linux, capabilities

An [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10737/167427) to the question "Allowing a regular user to listen to a port below 1024", specified giving an executable additional permissions using [`setcap`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setcap.8.html) such that the program could bind to ports smaller than 1024:

```
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /path/to/program
```

What is the correct way to undo these permissions?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To remove capabilities from a file use the `-r` flag

```
setcap -r /path/to/program
```

This will result in the program having no capabilities.

Comment: Well, that was a lot more evident after re-reading that short `man` page >.>

Comment: How can I confirm that the `setcap -r` command worked as intended?

Comment: @dotnetCarpenter Use `getcap`

Answer (score 22):

What @stephen-harris posted is right. But it removes all capabilities added to the program in one shot. To remove a specific capability, this should work (following the example in the question):

```
setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=-ep' /path/to/program
```

Notice the '-' sign. You can verify the capabilities of an executable as follows:

```
getcap /path/to/program
```

In case of `setcap -r`, all capabilities will be gone and the result of `getcap` will be empty where as the '-ep' just removes what you added with '+ep'.

This comes in handy when you gave multiple capabilities and want to selectively remove them.